# How to download JSON in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, webclient, json.net

I am trying to download a JSON in my Windows Phone app & then parse it. Searching through the internet i found that something like code above should work fine:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string result = wc.DownloadString("http://data.nature.com/sparql");
}
```

but in my windows phone app I can not assign `wc.DownloadStringAsync()` into a string type variable.

My Code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://184.22.234.221/bfunction/mjson.php"));
        var container = DeserializeFromJson<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(JsonStr);
```

Here, JsonStr is the string where I want to assign the downloaded JSON data. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://184.22.234.221/bfunction/mjson.php"));
```

And your DownloadStringCompleted handler is

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var container = DeserializeFromJson<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(e.Result); 
    }
```

Comment: it downloads the file as i can see data in e.Result in debugging mode , but container remains null .